# Combined tokenized words into single list in pandas

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with column as 'tokenized_texts':-

```
Tokenized_texts

[obama,america,counterpart]
[trump,election]
[development,china,canada]
..................
.................
................
[football,world,cup]
```

I want to convert it into single list which includes all tokenized words:

Expected output

```
[obama,america,counterpart,trump,election,development,china,canada,.......,world,cup]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [pandas.Series.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) to get the required list.

```
tokenized_texts = df['Tokenized_texts']
result = tokenized_texts.sum()

 >>>
 ['obama',
 'america',
 'counterpart',
 'trump',
 'election',
 'development',
 'china',
 'canada'
  ...
  ...
  ...
 ]
```

Comment: Is it anyway I can do this using for loop?

Comment: This is a lot faster than using `for` loop

Comment: Yeah, but I have also large number of lists without pandas dataframe there I can use it otherwise I need to convert it into dataframe first

Comment: You can convert it into `pandas.Series` instead of dealing with arrays. It will be lot easier and fast as well.